# Angular4 Google authentication through AngularFireAuth redirects back to source page before user can log into Google

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication

This was working before.

But now, the browser redirects to some lengthy url and then immediately returns to the source url. There is no chance to login into your google account.

**authentication service**

```js
  import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import * as firebase from 'firebase';
  import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
  import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
  import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
  import {AppUser} from './model';
  import {RepositoryService} from './repository.service';
  import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';


  @Injectable()
  export class AuthService {
    public user$: Observable<firebase.User>;
    constructor(private readonly afs: AngularFirestore, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, 
      private repo: RepositoryService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
      this.user$ = afAuth.authState;
    }

    login() {
            const returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('returnUrl') || '/';
            localStorage.setItem('returnUrl', returnUrl);
            alert('should be authenticating with google now');
            const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;
            this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(provider);
    }
```

```js
  providers: [AngularFireAuth, AuthService, AuthGuardService, RepositoryService, AdminGuardService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

Google Authentication is enabled for my database
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you inspect for any errors in the browser console or the network requests and report them?

Comment: I added the network tab http log for the full lifecycle i don't care about these keys being visible. it is just a test database.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to add them. I don't see any of your logs.

Comment: added.it seems afAuth.authState Observable<firebase.user> always returns one account. So I can log out, but when i go to initiate google login, the browser redirects and then this observable refires and the same user is back in context. i have put the videos on dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/2hnrjbu1a144xt3wrwyt1/AABqQhT7oahmS_gRB5WzGSUna?dl=0&oref=sha&r=AAiUeG11lKtintMCclGI8D-vpckVbWwDSfSU4Yudr4Rs9dLCJ8x66no_R3ebmOXDC5ECVWazVPb_6cKdMKeANuUTTE75ZwxhZ7YD-lnMxW-zjbHdvK31tUMiTIdxzeY3Cd7XsXQPN6SQ_HKLz3EdBCRk4-hYXg5OGeKTl7I0hdf6PPB-UwUFxFqObvci4bNPhxE&secure_hash=AABqQhT7oahmS_gRB5WzGSUna

Answer (score 0):

I had assumed that the firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect would allow you to sign in or out of your google account, by default, instead of just ignoring the fact that you might have different accounts you want to use to authenticate. However, to do this you have to set a custom parameter, as such:

```
     const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

     provider.setCustomParameters({
          prompt: 'select_account'
     });
     firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
```